# Login information regarding to weather site from twcservice.mybluemix.net

Tags: ibm-cloud, weather

I am trying to retrieve data from

https://twcservice.mybluemix.net/api/weather/v2/observations/current?units=m%E2%89%A5ocode=-36.84%2C174.76%E2%9F%A8uage=en-US

It prompts me for username and password. I have participated the sparkathon 
of IBM. Do you know if I can have some username, password for competition?

Many thanks,
Boris

Comment: This link might help: http://sparkathon.devpost.com/updates/4311-how-to-extend-your-bluemix-trial-for-sparkathon

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for support for a particular web site or service instead of directly about programming. Please see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) for details. Thank you.

Comment: I agree to close the question. Sorry for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks! I have solved it out by finding the answer from the tutorial at bluemix myself. The username and password is attached as encoded form and I can use them at the urllink.